# How to open a new form window within same window in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making an application in C#, and it has a menu, having forms linked with it, i want
that there should be a parent form, having a panel or window, when we click on any menu link, its .cs form should be loaded in the window, and so we can click on other windows, and their forms should replace the current one. Just like a common windows software.

Regards
Touseef Khan

Comment: How can you open a new window while not opening a new window at the same time?

Comment: Sounds like you going to need to do some DOM manipulation using clien side scripting. Hidden divs? ajax loading.. use c# todo all the server side processing and for example jquery to manipulate the page for best user experience. USing c# todo all that can be a mega pain.. all those postbacks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Form(Window) must be MDI

```
YourForm.IsMdiContainer = True

NewForm.MdiParent = YourForm;
NewForm.Show();
```

Comment: I have two new form first form is opening within same window but behind the first form,, not in front of. and 2nd one is larger then the parent so its opening outside......

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        var f2 = new Form2();
        f2.TopLevel = false;
        f2.FormBorderStyle =       System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        f2.Size = this.Size;
        f2.BringToFront();
        f2.Visible = true;
        this.Controls.Add(f2);
```