# Adding new form in the same window

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this link on my windows form in C# on visual studio:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Show another form.
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show(this);
            linkLabel1.LinkVisited = true;
        }
```

I want when i press the link,the new form which will be created to be on the same window and not appeared on another window.How can i do this?

Comment: So you mean, you want the controls in the new form to appear inside of the original form?

Comment: i just want to have the form in the same window.

Comment: You can use panels. It is like lake layers, so the top panel covers the bottom panel. Tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDOXzz_0gYE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `.Show` to `.ShowDialog`. This will make it a modal dialog "window".

Comment: I did it. But still the new form is shown as a new window. How is the new form shown in first (main) form's window? You know, installation forms, first form welcome screen, the second is agreement screen, the third is options screen... When we clicked "Next" button, new form (i think may be it is described as a screen) is shown same window (same frame). How can i do this? Your sincerely.

Comment: If adding ShowDialog does not work, why is this marked as answer? This can create confusion to people.

Answer (score 3):

The way I've usually seen this done is the show the new form and hide the previous one.

This gives the appearance of the same window being used.

Something like:

```
this.Hide();
f2.Show();
```

Comment: I was just about to post something like this :P

Answer (score 3):

A form is inherently a `Window`. If you want to do it without creating multiple Windows, create `UserControl`s and swap the visible `UserControl` on a Form.

Comment: i don't know how to create UserControl.Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can create UserControls and swap the visible UserControl on a Form.
To create user control check this link :  [create usercontrol](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jayendra/how-to-create-usercontrol-in-windows-form-application/)

Answer (score 0):

Form.ShowDialog() didn't work for me. So I tried "MDI Container". Please check the link below.

[How to open a new form window within same window in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019155/how-to-open-a-new-form-window-within-same-window-in-c)